# "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" when calling createJDBCTable()

Tags: java, oracle, apache-spark

I am getting this exception when I am trying to call `createJDBCTable()` method with `DataFrame` in Spark.

The code I am using:

```
private static final String CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password//host:port/sid";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "TESTTABLE";

DataFrame people = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, Person.class);
people.createJDBCTable(CONNECTION_URL, TABLE_NAME, true);
```

The exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4875)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.createJDBCTable(DataFrame.scala:1266)
    at com.org.spark.sample.SampleView.main(SampleView.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:480)
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: You should show your command.

Comment: please check the code. i have updated

Comment: So what does `DataFrame.createJDBCTable()` do? Can you print the **real** SQL statement that is being sent to the server?

Comment: Not an Oracle guy but your connection string looks wonky to me. Does that specific connection string work elsewhere, in code unrelated to Spark?

Comment: the method will create a table and insert the data from the text file

Comment: Docs here: https://goo.gl/gRwZyx (must use a shortener since the real URL won't work properly with the stackoverflow software)

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but is the value of `CONNECTION_URL` the actual value you're using, or is that just for an example?

Answer (score 0):

Just fyi.

*insertIntoJDBC* is working fine. Before invoking this call, I created the oracle table with the similar schema as that of the dataframe. All the rows were properly inserted.

But *createJDBCTable* for the same dataframe is failing with the below error. In this case I did not create any table in the database.

*java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended*

Answer (score -1):

This is code from Dataframe.scala

```
try { 

   if (allowExisting) { 

      val sql = s"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table" 

      conn.prepareStatement(sql).executeUpdate()
```

Unfortunately, this solution does not work with Oracle.

You may try to reproduce it by

- Logging into Oracle
- Running `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TESTTABLE` (should not work but produce the same error).

I will report this to Dev if you can confirm this (I do not have oracle installed anywhere near me to run quick test)

Solution: Create the table separately and use InsertIntoJDBC function instead.